# Como enviar e-mail pelo laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Eu tenho a rotina abaixo implementada no Laravel

```
$prestadores = \App\Prestador::all();

Mail::send('emails.listaprestadores',['prestadores' => $prestadores],
   function($message) use ($prestadores){
       $message->to('marcelo@mgsistemas.com.br', 'Marcelo Gomes');
       $message->subject('[Teste] Lista de Prestadores');
});
```

A `View` é o código abaixo. Não gera `exception`, mas o e-mail não é enviado.
Eu mudei a rotina para enviar um e-mail simples e o ele é enviado normalmente.
Acredito que esteja fazendo algo errado ao passar o `array`, mas eu peguei o exemplo na documentação do `Laravel`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title>Lista de Prestadores</title>
</head><body>
<table width="900" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Razão Social</th>
        <th>CNPJ</th>
        <th>Cidade</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($prestadores as $prestador)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $prestador->id ]}</td>
                <td>{{ $prestador->rezao_social ]}</td>
                <td>{{ $prestador->cnpj ]}</td>
                <td>{{ $prestador->cidade ]}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table><table class="table">
<tr>
    <td><span class="small">TrabalhoEmDia.com - Suas tarefas em Dia - </span>/td>    
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MarceloGomers, `$prestadores` é uma lista de informação muito grande, talvez o e-mail está sendo enviado, mas, bloqueado pelo servidor, visto talvez como **spam**, tente enviar um e-mail Html com 1 informação se ele for talvez seja esse `$prestadores`

Comment: Cheque também os dados da configuração de envio, a vezes está utilizando algum serviço que requer criptografia tls ou ssl...até mesmo o endereço smtp pode estar errado...enfim

Answer (score 2):

O problema foi resolvido incluindo no método `Mail::send` o `from`.

Envio correto:

```
Mail::send('emails.listaprestadores',['prestadores' => $prestadores],function($message) use ($prestadores){
   $message->to('marcelo@mgsistemas.com.br', 'Marcelo Gomes');
   $message->subject('[Teste] Lista de Prestadores')
   $message->from('marcelo@mgsistemas.com.br,'Marcelo');
});
```